# MYSQL Query To Find & Replace Two Phrases

Tags: mysql, search

Ive got this dynamic phrase on ALOT of posts with a different job title.

*"stats gathered across the U.S.        95%      of Flight Department Managers were males while        95%      were females"*

I need to to do a mysql query that will find and replace all posts on my wordpress that have both of these two sub phrases below.

*"stats gathered across the U.S.        95%      of"*

*"while        95%      were females"*

Not sure how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "stats gathered across the U.S. 95% of Flight Department Managers were males while 95% were females"   <-- This would need to be replaced with this -->   "stats gathered across the U.S. 5% of Flight Department Managers were males while 95% were females"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good resource which should have what you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html